# Is there a ES6 shorthand way to set a var equal to the data from function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example I have this.

```
api.get('show/?populate=author&limit=100').then(function(response) {
    vm.shows = response.data;
}).catch(function(error) {
    vm.error = `The API isn't responding.`;
    throw new Error(error);
});
```

Is there something like this that I can use?

```
api.get('show/?populate=author&limit=100').then(response.data => vm.shows);
```

Comment: I suppose it was inevitable that people would try to abuse new ES syntaxes to be clever. Your questions is aimed at solving the wrong problem. You wouldn't need to be concerned about setting a variable if you didn't have state mutations tangled up in your promise control flows.

Comment: Burying the warts with clever ES6 "shorthands" isn't going to help you. In fact, if you ever find yourself looking for a "shorthand" you're probably asking the wrong question; for the wrong reasons, too.

Comment: If you read what I'm writing, it sounds like I'm concerned about you solving your actual problem instead burying it with clever "shorthands" – it just sounds like you're interested in preserving your "design" as a matter of pride, regardless of whether there's a better way to do it.

Comment: what? the provided answer can only replaces the `.then` in your original code – it doesn't do anything to handle errors. Making your code shorter doesn't automatically make it better. Anyway, good luck. Post complete code examples next time if you want help that makes a real difference.

Comment: No, you posed a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – You wouldn't have to solve "ES6 shorthand way to set a var equal to the data from function" if you were ready/willing to revise the code that surrounds your "problem".

Comment: Um, okay. The OP never mentioned any problem; the question is just about syntax. Sometimes concise code is better. Assigning a variable asynchronously usually is horrible design; but could be valid. Or could be in a small testing program where that sort of correctness doesn't matter. You don't need to rage about the OP having their entire life philosophy wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't immediately assign to a variable, but you can shorthand the `response.data` with [*destructuring*](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html). Example:

```
// data becomes the "data" property of the callback's first argument
api.get('show/?populate=author&limit=100').then(({data}) => vm.shows = data);
```

Comment: This answer succeeds only in its ability to allow astonishingly bad code to thrive; under some illusion that a smaller wart is somehow less of a wart.

Comment: Now you have an asynchronous assignment. Better off doing `vm.shows = api.get('show/?populate=author&limit=100')` and then using `vm.shows.then()` Then at least all the reads would complete only after the value was written. Rather than many of them yielding either the prior value or undefined.

Comment: @DanD. I'm using vuejs and this loads on startup. If I set vm.shows to this promise then vuejs can't hook into the getters and setters. That's why I'm doing it this way.